# Iterate a script X times

Tags: jquery, function, loops

I have several functions that may or may not need to be repeated a certain number of times. The number of times is set by the user, and is stored in a variable: xTcount.

```
if (xTcount > 0) {
    for (i=0; xTcount <= i; i++) {
        $(document).miscfunction();
    }

}
```

I haven't actually tested the script above, as i'm sure it's incorrect. What makes what i want tricky, is that i don't want to have to code a "check xTcount" clause into every function that is repeatable. if possible, i'd like to create some master checker that simply repeats the next-called function xTcount times...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Repeat some things `xTcount` times? Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but it looks pretty simple:

```
for(var i = 0; i < xTcount; i++) {
    doSomething();
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

If the trouble is that you don't like the look of the `for` loop, or that your script requires you to build the same loop multiple times, you could extract it if you reeeaaallllly wanted to:

```
function repeat(fn, times) {
    for(var i = 0; i < times; i++) fn();
}

repeat(doSomething, xTcount);
// ...later...
repeat(doSomethingElse, xTcount);
```

Comment: I have a variety of functions that i could/want to loop. I don't want to have to go into each one and create the loop clause. It'd be more flexible if the loop looped the next called function.

Comment: - i re-read your post and you did provide a master repeater function, thank you, but i can't get it to work, is there anything i should know about using it? It looks straight forward enough...

Comment: @Jason: I'm out of town with limited internet access, so can't help a ton. Regardless, I've checked and the function runs correctly. Do you get an error message or anything? Remember, pass the function as an object, rather than calling it, e.g., with `function lol() { alert("lol") }` run `repeat(lol, 5)` rather than `repeat(lol(), 5)`.