# Repeat Function X times

Tags: jquery, function, loops

```
var xTcount = 3;

jQuery.fn.repeatFx = function(fn, times) {
    for(var i = 0; i < times; i++) fn();
}

$("#Art_C_M li").live('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var target = $this.hasClass('Double_It') ? 'doubler'
               : $this.hasClass('Float_R') ? 'floatR'
               : null;

    if (xTcount > 1) {repeatFx(target, xTcount);}
});
```

I'm trying to create a function that loops another function. Which function it loops varies though, i need a general function-looping function. I got help via this question: [Iterate a script X times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310206/iterate-a-script-x-times) I didn't want to append it since it's old now, and i'm not sure if that's recommended.

xTcount does change, based on another script (the user clicks a series of divs that contain numbers, the value is parsed into an int and stored, but for simplicity i'll leave it as 3 in this question.)

doubler and floatR are the names of the functions. I was hoping to use a case solution to get the function names, and pass it to the loop function.

I have the if clause so that users don't always have to click "1" in order for the effect to occur. So this way it only loops if it's greater than 1, and just once elsewise (which is taken care of in the base functions.)

*EDIT*

Modified code, to demonstrate a more explicit flow.

```
$(".Double_It").live('click', function() {
    repeatFx(drawCard, xTcount);
});
```

It appears that my function isn't being called. I added an append(text) to my Doubling function, if i call the function directly, it works and i get the appended text as a signal that it fired. But via this loop function, the text never shows up. So I infer that the function isn't being called.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes from your function names and it should work:

```
var target = $this.hasClass('Double_It') ? doubler
           : $this.hasClass('Float_R') ? floatR
           : null;
```

Of course, if you get null back then your code is going to break so you might want to check for it:

```
if ((xTcount > 1) && (target !== null) {.....
```

See an equivalent mock up here at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jameswiseman/HR9hz/)

```
function a() { alert("a"); }    
function b() { alert("b"); }    
function c(f){ f();}
var x = 1;  //change to '0' to see other function call
var fn = (x===0) ?  a : b;
c(fn);  //the alert will depend on whether a or b is assigned to fn
```

Comment: I'm not sure if your fiddle is comparable to what i want. What i do know is that my function isn't being called. I rewrote it to be more explicit, and still doesn't work. See OP.